# Flash Actionscript Dynamic Water Ripple

Tags: flash, actionscript, ripple

I was wondering if/how I can use this effect http://www.flash-filter.net/rain-drop-water-effect-download.phtml, or similar in Flash but instead of having the ripples follow the mouse, follow movie clips. I have a boat MC that I want to simulate moving through water.

Comment: have a look at this: http://www.derschmale.com/2008/08/03/water-ripples-revisited-as3-only-version/

Comment: Thanks you very much. Looks promising :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a similar water ripple effect, which also includes shading to make the ripples stand out better, using pixelbender. You can get the source [here](http://www.borisvanschooten.nl/blog/2010/05/04/pixel-bender-water-ripple-filter/). It shouldn't be too hard to adapt it to your own purposes.